# Why does SVG appear cropped despite of viewbox being proportionally equal to the width and height?

Tags: javascript, svg

I was just plaing around with [this SVG image](http://jsfiddle.net/BhZjV/332/), the svg looks as below:

```
<svg width=200 height=200 viewbox="0 0 240 240" >
    <path d="M220, 220
            A200, 200, 0, 0, 0, 20, 20
            L 20, 220
            Z"
    fill = "lightskyblue">
    </path>
</svg>
```

Now notice two things `width=200 height=200` the height and width set to `200` each and the viewbox set to `"0 0 240 240"`. Now if I set the viewbox to `"0 0 200 200"` the image appears cut, now why is that?

I believe that since the height and width is set to `200 and 200` each and the viewbox set to `"0 0 200 200"` the svg should be 100% visible, but it's not the case.

Comment: It sounds like you have a misunderstanding of what the viewBox does. It tells the renderer how much of the document you want to be visible inside your viewport (specified by the SVG width and height). If your viewBox is bigger than the viewport, everything in the document will get scaled down to fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your viewbox dimensions are set to `200`, but your path contains values of `220`, so the svg appears cropped because it extends beyond the scope of the viewbox